# python-rosdep in xenial archives, but dependencies are broken

Tags: rosdep, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So it seems that rosdep is in [universe for Xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-rosdep), which would be nice, if it worked. However, all it depends upon is python-yaml-- it doesn't depend on python-rospkg, python-catkin-pkg, or python-rosdistro, all of which it needs. So for example when one tries to initialize the database one is greeted with:

```
ImportError: No module named rospkg.os_detect
```

Is this a known issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226468/python-rosdep-in-xenial-archives,-but-dependencies-are-broken/) by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 347 on 2016-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Kyle,

thanks a lot for having a look at the packages and thanks to Dirk for pinging me. I've just pushed a fixed version into unstable, which should transition to Xenial soon. As Dirk wrote, the packages are still new, but we are happy to get bug reports, ideally through the Debian bug tracker or through Launchpad.

---

Originally posted by [Jochen Sprickerhof](https://answers.ros.org/users/182/jochen-sprickerhof/) with karma: 46 on 2016-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) on 2016-02-19**:
All fixed Jochen, thank you :) .